# React router redirect based on api response

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I'm using tmdb api multi search, I have a get request that returns back an array of items which have an object key and value. Some return 'media_type: tv', some return 'media_type: movie' I have two different routes set up for each of these.

Heres my App structure

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <div className='App'>
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
        {/* <Route exact path='/details/:type/:id' component={ItemDetails} /> */}
        <Route exact path='/details/movie/:id' component={MovieDetails} />
        <Route exact path='/details/tv/:id' component={TvDetails} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

Get Request

```
` performSearch = () => { // Requesting data from API
    let now = (this.now = Date.now());
    axios.get(`${URL}api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&query=${this.state.searchInput}${PARAMS}`)
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res.data.results);
            // Accepting response if this request was the last request made
            if (now === this.now) {
               this.setState({ searchResults: res.data.results});
            }
        });
}`
```

Functional Component that renders search result items

```
    const Suggestions = (props) => {
  const options = props.searchResults.map(r => (
    <li
      key={r.id} >
      <Link key={r.id} to={`/details/${r.id}`}>
        <a href='#t' className='rating'><i className='fas fa-star fa-fw' />{r.vote_average}</a>
        <img src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/${r.poster_path}`} alt={r.title} className='search-results-poster' />
        <a href='#t' className='search-results-name'>{r.name}</a>
        <a href='#t' className='search-results-title'>{r.title}</a>
      </Link>
    </li>
  ))
  return <ul className='search-results'>{options}</ul>
}
```

I'm thinking something like `if(props.media_type === tv){<Redirect component={TvDetails}/> else {<Redirect component={MovieDetails}`, I'm new to react-router so I'm not sure on how to do this

I have tried `<Link key={r.id} to={`/details/${props.searchResults.media_type.value}/${r.id}`}>`

but it says value is undefined though I can see it in my console.log [image]

edit: `<Link key={r.id} to={`/details/${r.media_type.value}/${r.id}`}>`

Takes me to /details/undefined/1234 , So I guess the value is still undefined?

Comment: I just got it working, though I used <Link key={r.id} to={`/details/${r.media_type}/${r.id}`}> Thanks though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`media_type` itself returns the string value in your case and an object with attribute value. So you just need to access `media_type` and not `media_type.value`

```
<Link key={r.id} to={`/details/${r.media_type}/${r.id}}`>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change 
`<Link key={r.id} to={/details/${r.media_type.value}/${r.id}}>` 
to 
`<Link key={r.id} to={/details/${r.media_type}/${r.id}}>`.

You don't need to add `.value` to get the value from the object